# C# get date between two dates with hours in same line

Tags: c#

In my program I have to filter the datagridview between dates but the problem is that I put a "datetime" so it puts the day/month/year + hours/minutes/seconds but I just want to filter by date, with the code I have in C# it only works if it doesn't have the hours/minutes ahead, does anyone know the process I have to do to put the dates and ignore the hour that is ahead?

**C# code:**

```
bimedicoesBindingSource.Filter = string.Format("med_data >= #{0:yyyy/MM/dd}# And med_data <= #{1:yyyy/MM/dd}#", dtpInicial.Value, dtpFinal.Value);
```

**Before filtering:**

[image]

**After filtering:**
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I'm not very familiar with datagridview, but the problem is that a DateTime without time is equivalent to the 0h of the date. So, you're actually filtering `>='2021-06-17T00:00' and <= '2021-06-17T00:00'`.

Just add one day to the end date and you will be fine.

```
bimedicoesBindingSource.Filter = string
    .Format(
        "med_data >= #{0:yyyy/MM/dd}# And med_data < #{1:yyyy/MM/dd}#", 
        dtpInicial.Value, 
        dtpFinal.Value.AddDays(1));
```

Notice that I changed the end condition to `<` instead of `<=` since it's the 0h of the next day.

Comment: AAAH thank you I have understood! Thanks for your help! @Magnetron